# Extract the correlation matrix from Monte Carlo data

Tags: monte-carlo, quantum-mechanics

I am writing my undergrad thesis on the harmonic oscillator on a lattice. So
far I have implemented the Metropolis Monte Carlo algorithm to generate
trajectories $x_j$ for $0 \leq j < N$, where $N$ is the number of time lattice
divisions.

I get a pretty good histogram for $|\psi(x)|^2$ and it matches the expectation
from the theory. Now I have to calculate the energy eigenvalues of the system.
The ground energy state can be calculated with $E_0 \propto \langle x^2
\rangle$ which has worked out so far.

The first energy, $E_1$, should be computable using the exponential slope of
the correlations, [Creutz and Freedman
(1980)](http://www.itkp.uni-bonn.de/~urbach/bnd/cf.pdf) wrote that this would
be doable with this: $$ E_1 = \frac{-1}{\Delta \tau} \log\left( \frac{\langle
x(0) x(\tau + \Delta \tau)\rangle}{\langle x(0) x(\tau) \rangle} \right)$$

With the $x_j$ that I have in my computations, I can calculate those
correlations to some value of $\tau$, limited by the $N$.

My advisor has given me a paper from [Blossier et al
(2009)](http://arxiv.org/abs/0902.1265) where they introduce a correlation
*matrix* like so (2.1):

$$ C_{ij} (t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle 0 | \hat O_i | n \rangle \langle 0 |
\hat O_j | n \rangle^* $$

Where $O_i$ are “some interpolating fields $O_i(x_0)$ already projected to a
definite momentum and other quantum number such as parity”.

From that, they show how the eigenvalues to the generalized eigenvalue problem
(GEVP) consisting of $C(t)$ and $C(t_0)$ will give the energy eigenvalues,
which I am interested in.

[Lüscher and Wolff
(1990)](https://physics.ucsd.edu/students/courses/spring2013/physics142/Labs/FinalProjects/LuscherWolff.pdf)
then write on page 245:

> In a numerical simulation, the correlation matrix $C(t)$ can be expected to
>   be computable for some range of $t$, and the basic technical problem then is
>   to extract the levels $W_\alpha$. from $C(t)$.

I do not see how I can get the $C_{ij}(t)$ out of my data. What are my fields
$O$ for a simple harmonic oscillator to start with? Are those the ladder
operators, so that $O_j$ = $(a^\dagger)^j$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to my advisor. The fields are just the powers of $x$. In those, the ladder operators exist, and should give me the desired correlations.